# If/Then/Fi Statement Syntax Error

Tags: linux, bash, unix, if-statement, bc

I am trying to execute the following code in a bash script to determine whether or not a number is greater than `1` or less than `1`.

**Bash Code:**

```
weight_check=`bc <<< "(.4+.4+.1+.1+.2)"`
if [[ ${weight_check} -lt "1.0" ]] || [[ ${weight_check} -gt "1.0" ]];
then
    echo "Incorrect Weights!"
    exit 0
fi
```

**Error:**

```
syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".2")
```

The sum of `${weight_check}` equals `1.2` but, the bash script doesn't see this...

The input numbers in `${weight_check}` will change so, I need this if/then/fi statement to be able to act dynamically.

Is my if/then/fi statement set up incorrectly?

Comment: How about an if/then/elif/fi statement. So
`if {weight_check} -eq "1.0" 
then 
... 
elif 
echo "Incorrect weights!" 
fi`

Comment: @Tom Fenech marked this as a duplicate post but, I just tried the answers that were given in that post and they did not solve my problem...

Comment: Additionally, I tried your method @liam_g and it did not work.

Comment: Do the test in `bc`, which will result in 0 or 1. You can test that in bash: `if (( $(bc<<<"$weight_check != 1.0") ));`. Or, with more typing: `if [[ $(bc <<<"$weight_check != 1.0") == 1 ]]; `

Comment: I am now receiving the following error: `syntax error near unexpected token fi`